# Node.js and jdbc : TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, jdbc, npm

I am new to nodejs and JavaScript. I am trying a very basic example of connecting MySQL to nodejs. I am using a npm jdbc package for this purpose. Below is the code snippet I am using for connection and getting below exception.
Can you please help me on this.

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var https =require('http');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var jdbc = new (require('jdbc'));
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');
var Pool = require('jdbc/lib/pool');
var _ = require('underscore');
// var cors = require("cors");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/view'));

server.listen(3000);
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');});

if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
  jinst.setupClasspath(['../mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar']);
}

var config = {
  url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB',
  user : 'root',
  password: 'root',
  minpoolsize: 2,
  maxpoolsize: 3,
  drivername: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
 };


//Initialize jdbc object
jdbc.initialize(config, function(err, res){ if (err){ console.log(err); } });

jdbc.open(function(err, conn) {
  if (conn) {
    //Run first query
    jdbc.executeQuery('show databases', function(err, results){
      if (err){ console.log(err); }
      else if (results) { console.log(results); }
    }); 
  }else{
    console.log('Connection object:' + conn);
    console.log(err);
  }
});

jdbc.close(function(err){
  if(err) { console.log(err); }
  else { console.log('Connection closed successfully!');}
});
```

Exception:

```
Field_Test\node_modules\jdbc\lib\pool.js:64
  this._url = config.url;
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at JDBC.Pool (<Dir>\node_modules\jdbc\lib\pool.js:64:21)
    at new JDBC (<Dir>\node_modules\jdbc\lib\jdbc.js:6:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Web\app.js:10:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with the require at the top, as per the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc, when you create a new instance you need to pass the config parameters you can do it two ways

```
var config = {url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB'}
var jdbc = new (require('jdbc'))(config);
```

or you can do it in line in the code

```
var Jdbc = require('jdbc');
...
var config = {url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB'}
var jdbc = new Jdbc(config)
```

In the context of your code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var https =require('http');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var Jdbc = require('jdbc');
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');
var Pool = require('jdbc/lib/pool');
var _ = require('underscore');
// var cors = require("cors");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/view'));

server.listen(3000);
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');});

if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
  jinst.setupClasspath(['../mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar']);
}

var config = {
  url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB',
  user : 'root',
  password: 'root',
  minpoolsize: 2,
  maxpoolsize: 3,
  drivername: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
 };

var jdbc = new JDBC(config);


//Initialize jdbc object
jdbc.initialize(config, function(err, res){ if (err){ console.log(err); } });

jdbc.open(function(err, conn) {
  if (conn) {
    //Run first query
    jdbc.executeQuery('show databases', function(err, results){
      if (err){ console.log(err); }
      else if (results) { console.log(results); }
    }); 
  }else{
    console.log('Connection object:' + conn);
    console.log(err);
  }
});

jdbc.close(function(err){
  if(err) { console.log(err); }
  else { console.log('Connection closed successfully!');}
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much url issue resolved , now I am getting Field_Test\app.js:40
jdbc.open(function(err, conn) {
     ^

TypeError: jdbc.open is not a function

Comment: maybe you are using an old version of the npm module but the docs suggest you use reserve as a function https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc#major-api-refactor  for example instead of using ```jdbc.open``` use ```jdbc.reserve```

Comment: Sure I will have a check